Remove "accept an answer" request from Low Quality Answers comment
I was going through the low quality answers review queue and noticed that, when the answer is by the user who asked the original question, the "This is a 'thank you' comment" asks the OP to accept an answer. This used to be an okay thing to do, but since then it's now discouraged, and even considered to be a community rules violation. As such, shouldn't the portion asking the OP to accept an answer be removed?

This made worse by the fact that "low quality answers" review comments are always made by the reviewer, instead of the Community bot. Having a button in the review queues that posts a community rules violation on your behalf seems like a dumb thing to have. (Granted, it does include a link to the review, so a mod probably wouldn't take action on the comment if it were actually flagged).
Is this just nitpicking a problem that doesn't exist and isn't really worth the time to fix? Not sure.
Regardless, this feature seems to be a change proposed / made (without status-completed) before the rules change. If it were made today, it probably would have been shot down.

This is more of an "onboarding" message in my opinion; I don't see an issue with it. The "historical" problem has been more than people used to ask people to accept their answer in the comments, which is frowned upon. of course, if the site as a whole had better onboarding, then we wouldn't need such things.

@ThomA I personally agree that it's not a (current) problem, and at worst it could give a new user the idea to ask for answer status (and they get their commented deleted / modmail warned). It's just small inconsistency / nitpick.

Maybe the Community bot should make these comments, then? Doesn't it work that way for other queues?

@KarlKnechtel First answers prompts you to either post as Community or yourself. Can't check any of the rest of the queues now, because I just got review banned for hitting "share feedback" to look at the options

@ipodtouch0218 devil's advocate: no you were not suspended for failing that one audit. It was merely the last one in a sequence and it is the sequence which triggers the suspension. Granted, it does suck extra hard when the audit system bites you in the behind when you were teetering on the edge. But that's the audit system; you either hate it or you really hate it.

I don't think it's an issue when the system generates a comment that provides this instruction after review by humans determines that to be the appropriate, intended course of action.
However, I do think it would be improved if it said

[...] Instead, upvote the answer, and accept the answer that you found most helpful if you are the question author.

or something similar instead, since sometimes users posting thank you answers are not the question asker and thus the advice to accept an answer does not apply to them.

It only uses the "accept the answer" template when the answerer == asker. Otherwise it uses a different template: "Please don't add 'thank you' as an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you found helpful."
